# Change Page Title in NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, express

How can I change the title for each page using `NodeJS`?

The `index.html` (not `.js` file) that is inside public folder is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta
     name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
   />
   <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />

  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

  <title>Default Titlte for all pages</title>
</head>
<body>
   <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
   <div id="root"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

How can I change the title dynamically whenever I navigate to any page?

Answer (score 3):

It's nothing else than changing page title in javascript by default like `document.title = 'title';` but it depends on your environment.

NodeJS itself lacks the ability to parse and transform HTML.

In express it would be like (a route based approach):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'title' });
});
```

Comment: Am not using express

Comment: Am not using express, so what is the solution, am only using materiel ui and NodeJs no other modules

Comment: see my updated answer, nodejs can't do that itself.

Comment: Yes I know, so what solution is simple for that ?

Comment: The solution would be to use Express in the Backend or some JS in the Frontend.

Comment: If you appreciate my answer you can upvote an mark it as accepted, that's the kind of reward here on SO to thank the person which provide help.

Comment: If I want to use it in Front End how should I do it exactly?

Comment: There are already a lot of answers on this question here on SO, search for them. Good luck.

Comment: What are you using?

Comment: @Bigga_HD I used now express but this code `res.render('index', { title: 'title' });` does NOT work

Comment: @Felix  I used now express but this code `res.render('index', { title: 'title' });` does NOT work

Answer (score 0):

### Try this, buddy:

```
    app.get('/simple',(req, res) => {
    res.render('simple.hbs',{title='mytitle'});
}
```

`/simple` is the *route* which will render your '*simple*' (`HTML`, `EJS`, `Handlebars`, etc. -depending on what your using) page and give it the brand new title as an extra option.
In this example, it would be ***mytitle*** :)

**Update:**  *an exaple using strictly HTML*
`app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    /***
    'template.html' - the filename of the template
    {} - the context - fill this with all the variables you 
                       want to use in your template
    ***/
    res.render('template.html', {title: 'My New Title'});
});`

Comment: Does not work, it does not change the title inside index.html at all !!!!

Comment: Did you put an equal (=) sing instead of a dot (.) ?? :)

Comment: am using backend and front end, I tried taht code in Back end !!!, and I use `router.get('/', async (req,res) => { ...... 
....
res.json({title: 'My New Title'});});`

Comment: I would suggest taking it easy. First try it with my exact code provided then experiment with stuff like async/ await, etc ... In addition to that, you have an extra set of symbols un the code you just provided. See anything fishy here: `});});` ? Good luck :)

Comment: The code backend and frontend works fine, only the title does not change at all!!!


`router.get('/', async (req,res) => {
  let result = await _buildSearchQuery(req);
  models.ListingPost.findAll({
    include: [models.HousingType,models.ListingImage],
    exclude: [models.Chat],
    where: result.searchQuery,
    order: result.order
  }).then(listings =>{     
    var body = convertSequilizeToObject(listings);       

    res.json({title: 'My New Title'});
  });
});`

Answer (score 0):

res.write(`<head>
     <title>My title</title>
     </head>`);

Try the above code at (app.get) endpoint of different page Accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I am using `EJS template Engine` so using `EJS` I do this using following method

in Route Do this

```
router.get("/add", function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('category/add', { layout: "layoutMain", title: "Add New Category" });
});
```

**here `layoutMain` is the layout file that contain css, js links,sidebar and header part of the website that part is shared to all pages of website so we will make it common**

for more please find `EJS LAYOUT` document on the official doc.

now in the `layoutMain` file do following

```
<title><%- title%></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: You can't do it while it is inside the public folder, because the idea of public folder is to show static pages, images, styles ,client side scripts etc. If you still want to change title and don't want to move the file out of the public folder skip to the last paragraph.

You need to use any template Engine like `EJS` for that, first rename your `.html` file to `.ejs` then assuming you are using Express.JS you can pass data to your design page (Note: this happens at the server-side).

In your `index.js`

```
app.get("/path/to/your/page",function(req,res){
    res.render("path/to/your/layout/index.ejs",{
       title:"Your Title Here"
    });
});
```

In your `index.ejs` (not the full code, add rest of the html)

```
<head>
    <title><%- title %></title>
</head>
```

You can learn more about how to use template engines here [Using EJS with Express](https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express) .
Note: the code is a simple example the full code of using Express and EJS are widely available on youtube, documentations, stackoverflow.

And why do you want to change title with Node.JS ? You can use client side JS to change title whenever you want, eg: when user clicks a login button and a login popup opens you can use `document.title="Login";` and when user clicks register button and a register popup opens you can set title `document.title="Register";` , both was in the same page.